# Homology groups of a Grassmannian

Tags: algebraic-geometry, homology-cohomology, grassmannian

I can't manage to calculate the homology and comology groups of the Grassmannian $G(k+1,n+1)$. I know the definition of homology group and I read which are the homology groups of a Grassmannian, but I can't understand how to get those groups. Can anyone help me?

Comment: presumably you mean singular (co)homology? you can use cellular (co)homology and Schubert cell decomposition. There is a detailed computation in Griffiths and Harris, Chapter 1

Comment: @IvanBodhidharma Thank you for the tip, I will have a look at it. Have a nice day.